# change value of a dynamically created JLabel (Java)

Tags: java

I want to create a number of labels dynamically, so I found this code:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        panel.add(new JLabel("Label"));
        panel.validate();
    }
});
```

It works great, but I can't change the text it's showing because I can't call it. For example like: `label.setText("Labeltext Changed!");`

So my question is: How can I give each dynamically created label a name, so I can change their values?

Comment: How do you want to define which one to change? Do you want to be able to edit them by index?

Comment: yes, or an upcounting number like

1.setText();
2.setText();
3.setText();
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your labels in a `List<JLabel>`.

```
private List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<>();

...

public void yourMethod() {

    ...

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("Label");
            labels.add(newLabel);
            panel.add(newLabel);
            panel.validate();
        }
    });

    ...

}
```

Then to get it just do something like `labels.get(0).setText("my text");`.

Note that you can shorten the `ActionListener` code with a lambda expression:

```
button.addActionListener(arg0 -> {
    JLabel newLabel = new JLabel("Label");
    labels.add(newLabel);
    panel.add(newLabel);
    panel.validate();
});
```